Queuing and running sequentially Cloud Run jobs triggered by BigQuery table updates using Eventarc
I created an Eventarc Trigger called by google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob to trigger a cloud run job on BigQuery table changes (insert, update, delete) that could happen any time during the day.
This works pretty well as it triggers a Cloud Run instance (whenever a change occurs on my BQ table) that reads data from the BQ table and automatically creates/updates/deletes Jira issues.
The problem is that it might take more or less time to finish processing data which could lead to issues when two changes happen very quickly one after the other on table. In that case, the second change could trigger a cloud run instance in parallel of the first one that did not finish processing data yet.
So, I'm trying to make it more reliable at scale by forcing jobs to be executed in sequence instead of having issues with parallelization.
Is it possible to still use event-based triggering of the same cloud run endpoint (with eventarc) while queuing the executions ?
I've started looking at Cloud Tasks and Workflows but could not manage to build a system that works with these resources.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Please refer to this document of Cloud Tasks. if it doesn't solve your issue, Can you please tell me what you are looking for?

Cloud Task is indeed la solution. Set a max concurrent dispatch to 1 to avoid concurrency. https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues#rate However, there is no direct integration with Eventarc. So there are 2 options: either you create a CLoud Run that create the task, or you use a Cloud Logging sink to PubSub, and create a Push Subscription with create a task in a URI Override Task queue https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues#update_or_remove_queue-level_routing Can sound more complex, but's it's only configuration, no additional CLoud Run to deploy and pay.

Thank you @guillaumeblaquiere for the two options.
If I understand well, the first option would be something like : keep eventarc to trigger a new cloud run that creates tasks. Each task is then queued to trigger the existing cloud run that processes data.  Is that right ?
I need to look into the second one into more details. Do you have any examples of such a setup ?
Thanks again !

I tested the first approach so far. It works OK but I am not sure if this solves the issue of concurrent runs. The schedule from now parameter leads to have ETAs for your tasks very close to each other. So, even though tasks are not dispatched at the same time (because few seconds may separate them) the problem of concurrent run could still happen in cloud run instances if the jobs requires a few minutes to complete. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Based on your great question, I written an article. It explains the pros and cons of the 2 options.
You can find the technical sample in my Github repository.
I also shared a hack, if you want to have fun!
